# prove this inequality $x^{n+1}\geq (n+1) x-n$

Tags: inequality, induction

I tied to prove this by induction

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R_+} ,\forall n \in\mathbb{N}:x^{n+1}\geq (n+1) x-n$$

I know it holds for $n=1$ but I get stacked after this step.

Comment: What about $x=-2, n=5$? You will get $-32 \geq  -18$, which is obviously false.

Comment: Hint: don't use induction: write $x^{n+1} = ((x-1) + 1)^{n + 1}$ and use the binomial theorem. (I assume that $n$ is intended to be a positive integer.)

Comment: Given talbi's comment, it should be stated in question what restriction there is on $x.$ [I take it you require $n$ a positive integer, right?]

Comment: @talbi re-raid the question ; x>0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $x\geq 0, n\geq 0$.

Define $f(x)=x^{n+1}-(n+1)x+n$, then $f'(x)=(n+1)(x^n-1)$.

The function is monotone increasing in $[1,+\infty)$ and decreasing in $[0,1]$. So the minimal is $f(1)=0$.

Then, $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\geq 0$, i.e., $x^{n+1}\geq(n+1)x-n$.

---

1.$n=1$ holds.

2. Assume $n=k$ holds. then, $x^{k+1}\geq(k+1)x-k, \forall x$.

Then, for $n=k+1$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x^{k+2}&=x*x^{k+1}\\
&\geq (k+1)x^2-kx\\
&=(k+2)x-(k+1)-(k+2)x+(k+1)x^2-kx+(k+1)\\
&=(k+2)x-(k+1)+(k+1)(x-1)^2\\
&\geq (k+2)x-(k+1).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
So, the inequality also holds for $k+1$

3. Therefore, the inequality holds for all positive integers.

Comment: yeah correct but I want to use induction

Comment: I have updated the solution in the answer.

Comment: exactly Great, so now can you use this result to prove the AM GM inequality

Comment: Do you have any good ideas to prove the AM GM inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution using AM-GM: $\frac{x^{n+1}+n}{n+1}=\frac{x^{n+1}+1+1+...+1}{n+1} \geq \sqrt[n+1]{x^{n+1}\cdot 1\cdot 1 \cdot ... \cdot1} = x \implies $ $$x^{n+1}\geq (n+1) x-n.$$

---

In addition, there is a solution where you don't need to know any AM-GM or use induction:
$x^{n+1}-x\ge n(x-1) \iff x(x^n-1)\geq n(x-1) \iff x(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x+1)\geq n(x-1) \iff$ $$(x-1)(x^n+x^{n-1}+...+x^2+x-n)\geq 0$$ If $x\ge1$, then $x^n+x^{n-1}+...+x^2+x\ge1+1+...+1=n$, and if $x \le 1$, then $x^n+x^{n-1}+...+x^2+x\le1+1+...+1=n$, so
$$(x-1)(x^n+x^{n-1}+...+x^2+x-n)\geq 0 \implies x^{n+1}-x\ge n(x-1)$$

Comment: haha I want this to prove the AM-GM , so i can not use it :)

Comment: @El-Mo I see. I will update the solution with the induction solution soon.